# Use forms in wordpress which goes back to itself?

Tags: mysql, forms, wordpress

i'm working on a wordpress site using buddypress. So, i'm making a page where you can see members and search for them using a database: wp_users.
This works fine if i have it as a php when adding it to a wp page it shows up correctly but when clicking submit I get a 404 error.

This is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE  HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta  http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;  charset=utf-8">
    <title>Search  Contacts</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  #spacer {
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
}
  </style>
  </head>
  <p><body>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <form  method="post" action=""  id="searchform">
      <p>
        <input name="name"  type="text">
        <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Søk">
      </p>
      <p>Tips: du kan søke etter adresse, navn og e-post.</p>
    </form>

  <table width="600">
            <tr>
              <th width="200" height="50">Navn</th>
                <th width="200">&nbsp;</th>
              <th width="200">E-post adresse</th>
            </tr>  
<?php
/* Change next two lines  if using online*/
$db="skynnaks_skyn";
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'skynnaks_skyn', '*password*');

if (! $link) die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db , $link) or die("Couldn't open $db: ".mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM wp_users" )
          or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($result) {

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
$_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
#echo "<tr><a href='#'>".$row['display_name']."</a>";
echo "<td><a href="."/members/".$row['user_nicename']."/profile/>".$row['display_name']."</a></td>";
#echo "<a href=" '.$row['id'].'>Bruker: ".$row['user_url']."</a>";
echo "<td><a href=".$row['user_url'].">".$row['user_url']."</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href=".'mailto:'.$row['user_email'].">".$row['user_email']."</a></td></tr>";
}
}


?>
</table>
    <div id="spacer">
     <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(preg_match("/^[  a-zA-Z]+/", $_POST['name'])){
  $name=$_POST['name'];
  //connect  to the database
  $db=mysql_connect  ("localhost", "skynnaks_skyn",  "*password*") or die ('I cannot connect to the database  because: ' . mysql_error());
  //-select  the database to use
  $mydb=mysql_select_db("skynnaks_skyn");
  //-query  the database table
  $sql="SELECT  ID, user_login, user_nicename FROM wp_users WHERE user_login LIKE '%" . $name .  "%' OR user_nicename LIKE '%" . $name ."%'";
  //-run  the query against the mysql query function
  $result=mysql_query($sql);
  //-create  while loop and loop through result set
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
          $loginName  =$row['user_login'];
          $niceName=$row['user_nicename'];
          $ID=$row['ID'];
  //-display the result of the array

  echo "<ul>\n";
  echo "<li>" . "<a href="."/members/".$loginName."/profile/>".$niceName."</a>" ;
  echo "</ul>";
  }
  }
  else{
  echo  "<p>Please enter a search query</p>";
  }
  }
?>
  </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>


  </body>
</html>
</p>
```

PS: I cant use default permalinks due buddypress plugin. And i know that buddypress comes with a members search, but i have installed norwegian language pack, but it wont work with members search in buddypress.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [this problem](http://www.cabeeb.com/2009/09/posting-a-form-to-a-wordpress-page/),

so change your input tag name with any specific name attribute.

for example,

```
<input name="membername" type="text" />
```

but don't forget to get variable with same from `$_POST`

Comment: @user1219796 Is url same as the page url after posting form? Did you check it?

Comment: figured it out :)
For the one who want to make this "search" you will need to change button from submit --> formsubmit ...
I also removed the "go" extension and action = "" (Nothing)